# Finding all ordered quadruples $(a, b, c, d)$ of primes

Tags: systems-of-equations

Find all ordered quadruples $(a, b, c, d)$ of primes such that
\begin{align*}
13a^2 + b^2 + 13c^2 &= 2b(3a + 2c) \\
a^3 −(bc)^3 &= (b+c−a)d+2021.
\end{align*}

---

A quick WolframAlpha search yielded that the answer to this was no pairs, but I wasn't quite sure how to derive it.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation, considered as quadratic equation in $c$, has no real solution in $c$, except for the case $3b=13a$.

Then we have $a=3$ and $b=13$, so that the first equation gives $c=2$. This indeed solves the first equation. However, then the second equation is $6d + 9785=0$, so that $d$ is not an integer. Contradiction.